# Why is the tensor product of abelian group and $\mathbb Q$ a rational vector space?

Tags: tensor-products

If $G$ is an abelian group, then it is known that the tensor product $G\otimes_\mathbb{Z}\mathbb Q$ can be made a $\mathbb Q$-vector space by setting $r\cdot(g\otimes q):=g\otimes(rq)$ and then "extending linearly". I fail to see why such "extension" is well defined...

I need to show that if $\sum_i g_i\otimes q_i=\sum_j h_j\otimes p_j$, then also $\sum_i g_i\otimes rq_i=\sum_j h_j\otimes rp_j$. It suffices to show this for $r=\frac{1}{n}$. My approach is to note that $n\sum_ig_i\otimes\frac{q_i}{n}=n\sum_ih_i\otimes\frac{p_i}{n}$, but I don't know how to proceed from here. Part (1) of Theorem 4.27 in [these notes](https://kconrad.math.uconn.edu/blurbs/linmultialg/tensorprod.pdf) seems like could be useful, but I wouldn't know how to apply this result. Could someone please provide insight?

Comment: In general, given a ring homomorphism $A \to B$, the functor $C \mapsto C \otimes_A B$ produces, in an obvious way, a $B$-module from the $A$-module $C$. In this case, we are looking at the inclusion map $\mathbb{Z} \to \mathbb{Q}$, noting that an Abelian group is just a $\mathbb{Z}$-module. This concept is known as “extension of scalars”; other examples include the complexifixation of a real vector space.

Comment: You do *not* want Theorem 4.27 in that link. Use Theorem 6.4. Section 6 is what you want to read: it shows how an $R$-module $M$ and a ring $S$ containing $R$ (thus an $R$-module in a natural way) let you turn the $R$-module $S \otimes_R M$ into an $S$-module where $s'(s \otimes m) = (s's) \otimes m$ for all $s' \in S$ and elementary tensors $s \otimes m$ in $S \otimes_R M$. Watch out for the initial generality in Section 6: the ring homomorphism $f \colon R \to S$ when $R \subset S$ is just the inclusion mapping, so $f(r)$ is $r$ viewed inside $S$ (with $R = \mathbf Z$ and $S = \mathbf Q$).

Answer (score 2):

If $M$ is an abelian group, and $R$ is a ring, a “scalar multiplication” which makes $M$ an $R$-module is *the same as* a ring homomorphism $$R \to \operatorname{End}_\mathbb{Z}(M).$$ Indeed, if $\phi$ is the above map, then for each $r \in R$ and $m \in M$ we define $rm := \phi(r)(m)$.

---

Now, for each $r \in \mathbb{Q}$, the $\mathbb{Z}$-bilinear map $$G \times \mathbb{Q} \to G \otimes_ \mathbb{Z} \mathbb{Q}, \quad (g,q) \mapsto g \otimes (rq)$$ induces a $\mathbb{Z}$-linear map $\mu_r \colon G \otimes_ \mathbb{Z} \mathbb{Q} \to G \otimes_ \mathbb{Z} \mathbb{Q}$. Therefore, we have a map $$
\mu \colon \mathbb{Q} \to \operatorname{End}_\mathbb{Z}(G \otimes_ \mathbb{Z} \mathbb{Q}), \quad r \mapsto \mu_r
$$ which can be easily shown to be a ring homomorphism. Then, $\mu$ gives us the desired $\mathbb{Q}$-vector space structure: $$
r(g \otimes q) := \mu(r)(g \otimes q) = \mu_r(g \otimes q) = g \otimes (rq).
$$

Comment: It's probably worth saying a word about why $r \mapsto \mu_r$ is a ring hom (though I agree it's easy, it might _not_ be easy for OP)

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to work this hard, this follows directly from the universal property of the tensor product. This universal property says that giving a linear map $M \otimes N \to P$ is the same thing as giving a bilinear map $M \times N \to P$, and the tensor product is constructed exactly to make this work. Now set $P = M \otimes N$ and let $f : N \to N$ be any linear map. Then

$$M \times N \ni (m, n) \mapsto m \otimes f(n) \in M \otimes N$$

is a bilinear map (because $f$ is linear) so by definition it extends to a linear map $M \otimes N \to M \otimes N$. So $f$ naturally gives a map on the tensor product; a little more effort shows the more general fact that taking tensor products is [functorial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functor).

Answer (score 0):

As you've said, we want to define $r \cdot (g \otimes q)$ by $g \otimes (rq)$, and we want to extend this linearly. That is, we define

$$
r \cdot \sum g_i \otimes q_i = \sum g_i \otimes (r q_i)
$$

Now, when we define the tensor product, we first define an equivalence relation on the elements of the form
$g \otimes q$, then we just declare elements of the tensor product to be sums of equivalence classes.

In particular, we only need to check well-definedness on the basic elements of the form $g \otimes q$.

But the only relation we quotient by is  $g n \otimes q \sim g \otimes n q$, for $n \in \mathbb{Z}$. So to check well-definedness we need to show

$$
r \cdot (gn \otimes q) \sim r \cdot (g \otimes nq)
$$

which is obviously true:

$$
r \cdot (gn \otimes q) = gn \otimes rq = g \otimes nrq = g \otimes rnq = r \cdot (g \otimes nq)
$$

Of course, there are other, less computational, approaches to this problem, which you can find in the other answers.

---

I hope this helps ^_^