# Rank and dimension dilemma for modules

Tags: algebraic-topology, modules, homological-algebra, tensor-products, free-modules

Let $R$ be a field of characteristic zero, and $M$ be a $\mathbb{Z}$-module. Knowing that $R\otimes M$ is a vector space, can we deduce that $M$ is a **free $\mathbb{Z}$-module** and $\text{rank}(M)=\dim_R(R\otimes M)$? And maybe finding a basis in $M$.

I came up with this problem trying to understand why

$$\text{rank}\ H_p(X,\mathbb{Z})=\dim_R H_p(X,R)$$.

It is known that $H_p(X,R)\simeq R\otimes H_p(X,\mathbb{Z})$ and $H_p(X,R)$ is a vector space over $R$.

By $H_p(X,R)$ I mean the $p$-th singular homology $R$-module (i.e. vector space when $R$ is a field) associated to $X$ and by $H_p(X,\mathbb{Z})$ the $p$-th homology $\mathbb{Z}$-module associated to the topological space $X$.

Comment: how are you getting that homology is torsion free? Take $X=\mathbb RP^2$ and $p=1$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- For any abelian group $M$, $\mathbb{Q} \otimes M$ is a rational vector space (see [Why is the tensor product of abelian group and $\mathbb Q$ a rational vector space?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4483336/why-is-the-tensor-product-of-abelian-group-and-mathbb-q-a-rational-vector-spa), for example).
- There are abelian groups which contain torsion.

So knowing that $\mathbb{Q} \otimes M$ is a rational vector space does not let you conclude that $M$ is torsion-free, because it need not be. It is, however, true that if $M$ is finitely generated, then its rank (meaning the rank of its free part) is equal to the dimension of $\mathbb{Q} \otimes M$. You can prove this using the classification of finitely generated abelian groups, combined with the fact that $A \otimes (B \oplus C) \cong (A \otimes B) \oplus (A \otimes C)$ and the isomorphisms $\mathbb{Q} \otimes \mathbb{Z} \cong \mathbb{Q}$ and $\mathbb{Q} \otimes \mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z} \cong 0$ for $n > 0$.

Comment: Why do you use $\mathbb{Q}$ instead of $R$?

Comment: (a) to be specific and (b) because $\mathbb{Q}$ is the most commonly used field of characteristic zero in algebraic topology in the context of homology computations. You can replace with an arbitrary field of characteristic zero if you like.

Answer (score 2):

take $M=\mathbb Z \oplus \mathbb Z/2$ and $R=\mathbb Q$ as a counterexample.

Maybe assume that $H_p(X, \mathbb Z)$ to be a finitely generated module and use the classification theorem for finitely generated abelian groups. Note that $\mathbb Q \subseteq R$. Can you show one side of the inequality?

Comment: Thanks! I made a mistake in my calculations. You are right! I see that if $H_p(X,\mathbb{Z})$ is finitely generated then a basis of $H_p(X,\mathbb{Z}):\{e_1,e_2,...,e_n\}$ will produce a generator set for $H_p(X,R)$, namely $\{1\otimes e_i\}$. But how do I get the linear independence?

Comment: What do you mean by $\mathbb{Q}\subset R$?

Comment: I mean that every field of characteristic zero contains the rationals